# How to attach javadocs in java ee netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, javadoc

I am developing for a project, and sometimes I encounter some codes that I would like to read the documentations about. But I am having "Javadoc not found" in my tooltip,and attaching javadocs in my netbeans. Also there is this online api documentation ([Online Java EE API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)) but sometimes its a bit tedious for checking it everytime, is there a way that i can integrate it somehow in my netbeans?

I tried the Attach Javadoc... button below, but nothing seem to work.

[image]

Also, if you have a link where i can download a .jar of java-ee-apidocs, thanks.
I already tried downloaded [Java EE 6 Update 2 Javadocs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eedocs-419425.html#java_ee_6u1_docs-JPR), are there updated versions for Java EE7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Go to Tools > servers > select_your_server > Javadoc
Click Add Zip/Folder
Browse for javadocee6.zip
Press Close

or

Method 2:
go to libraries > properties > select a jar > edit > browse for javadocee6.zip >done!

Comment: There is no javadoc tab after selecting server. Mine is glassfish btw.

Answer (score 0):

I use WildFly server and it has the Javadoc tab but adding it there didnt work.

I had to right click "javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar" on my maven project dependencies tree, then choose 'Add local Javadoc' and point to the file I downloaded from https://javadoc.io/doc/javax/javaee-web-api/latest/index.html to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Gradle built Java EE Web Application.

Under the project's Configurations->default[runtimeElements] there's the javaee-api:8.0.1. If I right-click that, I have the option to "Download Javadoc". Once I do that, I see the JavaDoc descriptions in the tooltip.

There's also a "Show Javadoc" option that will render a web page with the full Java EE API.